# Understanding the map/reduce process. Have few questions

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Below are the steps in serial and there are questions in between. Please correct me if I am wrong and elaborate a little bit.

- Client/user submits the request to the JobTracker. JobTracker is a software that resides in a name node.
- JobTracker divides the job into small sub-problems and gives to the TaskTracker. TaskTracker is the software that resides in data node. TaskTracker may do it again leading to multi-level tree structure.
- The mapping step happens only in TaskTracker not in JobTracker?
- Shuffle and sort takes place. Does this step takes place in Mapper step or Reducer step?
- The output of shuffle and sort is fed into Reducer step?
- The reducer step happens only in JobTracker not in TaskTracker?
- Reducer step i.e. JobTracker not TaskTracker combines the data and gives output to the client/user.
- Only 1 reducer is used for combining the result?

Thanks

Comment: This style question is really hard to answer on stackoverflow. Also, just about every line in this is wrong... so not sure where you are deriving these assumptions from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Client/user submits the request to the JobTracker. JobTracker is a software that resides in a name node.

JobTracker is a daemon that can reside in a separate machine other than the namenode.

> JobTracker divides the job into small sub-problems and gives to the TaskTracker.

The JobTracker farms out MapReduce tasks to specific nodes in the cluster, ideally the nodes that have the data, or at least are in the same rack.

> TaskTracker is the software that resides in data node. TaskTracker may do it again leading to multi-level tree structure.

Usually yes. TaskTracker can run alone but it definitely needs a datanode to work with, somewhere.

> The mapping step happens only in TaskTracker not in JobTracker?

Map Tasks are launched by tasktracker

> Shuffle and sort takes place. Does this step takes place in Mapper step or Reducer step?

Shuffle and sort process is actually between the map phase and the reduce phase. But they are relevant only for the reduce phase. Without the reduce phase shuffle and sort will not take place. So, we can say - Reducer has 3 primary phases: shuffle, sort and reduce.

> The output of shuffle and sort is fed into Reducer step?

In shuffle and sort, the framework fetches the relevant partition of the output of all the mappers, via HTTP. Input to the Reducer is the sorted output of the mappers.

> The reducer step happens only in JobTracker not in TaskTracker?

Reduce tasks are launched by TaskTracker.

> Reducer step i.e. JobTracker not TaskTracker combines the data and gives output to the client/user.

Reduce tasks are something that are supposed to runs in parallel in several nodes and emit results to HDFS. You can read the output data from the final data sets from different reducers and combine them in the MapReduce driver if you like.

> Only 1 reducer is used for combining the result?

It will depend on the what you want to do. But having a single reduce task will surely bring down performance due to lack of parallelism, if you have large data to process in a single reduce task.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you need this: [Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, 3rd Edition.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021773.do) Most useful guide on this topic.

Some notes:

1. Hadoop mainly is combination of 2 things: HDFS as "storage" and MapReduce framework as "CPU".
2. NameNode is related to HDFS, JobTracker is related to MapReduce. MapReduce uses HDFS service but JobTracker and NameNode is completely different services and don't have to be located on the same node.
3. Again DataNode is HDFS entity but TaskTracker is component of MapReduce and they are independent. In practice they often located on the same node but it is not something that is fixed.
4. Job steps itself are performed by TaskTracker. JobTracker is like scheduler. This is related both to Map and Reduce steps. Don't forget about Combiner.
5. No, you can use more than 1 Reducer and you can control this and you can use up to 1 combiner per each mapper as combiner takes place right after mapper.
6. Shuffle process is related to mapper (or combiner) output so logically its closer to mapper than to reducer but you actually should not rely on this. Your freedom is to take next record and process. In addition if 0 reducers are configured you will not have things like shuffle.
7. Don't try to replace real knowledge with such Q&A site advices. Doesn't work :-).

Hope this help.